# Populate a dynamic dropdown based on value inserted in the text-box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, auto-populate

Please someone help, I am really going to be crazy!.

I have a PHP form with some questions and one of the question is "Which are your favourite movies?" for which I used jQuery auto-complete feature which works fine!. However, It is possible that users forget the name of a movie, but remember an actor that played in that movie. So, I would like to enable user typing an actor/actress name in the auto-complete textbox (e.g., "Tom Cruise") and based on inserted actor name, a dynamic dropdown menu should be added which contains list of movies that the actor (e.g, Tom Cruise) has played in them.

This is what I tried but not work :((

```
<html>
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?> 
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
</head>

<body>

<input type="textbox" name= "tag" id="tags">
<select id="movieImdbId" name="movieImdbId[]" multiple="multiple" width="200px" size="10px" style=display:none;>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
                      $("#tags").autocomplete({
                        source: "actorsauto.php",  //php file which fetch actors name from DB
                        minLength: 2,
                        select: function (event, ui){
                        var selectedVal = $(this).val(); //this will be your selected value from autocomplete
                 // Here goes your ajax call.      
                       $.post("actions.php", {q: selectedVal}, function (response){
                // response variable above will contain the option tags.            
                       $("#movieImdbId").html(response).show();
              });
           }
          });     
       });                     
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

and this is actions.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if(isset($_GET['q']) && !empty($_GET['q'])){
 $q = $_GET['q'];

include('Connection.php');  //connection to the DB
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT movieImdbId FROM movie_roleNames WHERE castName = :q");
$sql->execute(array(':q' => $q));
$html = "";

while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
  $option = '<option value="' . $row->movieImdbId . '">' . $row->movieImdbId . '</option>';
  $html .= $option;
}
echo $html; // <-- this $html will end up receiving inside that `response` variable in the `$.post` ajax call.
exit;
}
?>
```

**Question:** Why when user insert an actor name in the text-box, the dropdown menu is populated but **is EMPTY**?

Comment: Is the data being returned from PHP successfully?

Comment: @tymeJV: I don't know how to test that, I put `print_r($_POST);` at the beginning of html/js file , and what I see in my localhost is Array ( )... so I think it returns an empty array...

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax call, you send a `POST` request, and you try to get the params with `$_GET` in you php.

```
$.post("actions.php", {q: selectedVal}, function (response){
    // response variable above will contain the option tags.            
   $("#movieImdbId").html(response).show();
});
```

change the `$.post` method to `$.get`.

OR

```
if(isset($_GET['q']) && !empty($_GET['q'])){
    $q = $_GET['q'];
}
```

change `$_GET` to `$_POST`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't change the result .. :(

Comment: In your `actions.php` ajax call's callback, try `console.log` the `response` and see what it is

Comment: like this: `... console.log(response); $("#movieImdbId").html(response).show(); ...`

Comment: Thanks, I did it, nothing has changed:(